# Input .csv data (float & strings) matrix in C++

Tags: c++, csv, input

I have wrote the following C++ input function. It takes a .CVS file and returns a matrix (type `vector < vector< double>>`). It only works for numerical values in the .CSV file, because it takes values as c-strings and `atof()` function convert them into float.

I would like to change this function and improve it so it can input not only numerical data, but both numerical and strings, no matter what column or row contains what kind of data.

Any idea how that could be done? Thanks in advance!.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> Vector;
typedef vector<Vector> Matrix;

Matrix input(string& file_name) {
    string line;
    Matrix M;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the name of a .csv file: ";
        cin >> file_name;
        string data("./path/" + file_name + ".csv");
        ifstream file(data);

        if (file.is_open()) {
            while (getline(file, line)) {
                Vector ROW;
                istringstream iss(line);
                string value;
                while (getline(iss, value, ',')) {
                    /* HERE I TAKE THE VALUES OF THE .CSV MATRIX AS C-STRINGS
                       AND CONVERT THEM AS FLOATS                          */
                    ROW.push_back(atof(value.c_str()));
                }
                M.push_back(ROW);
            }
            file.close();
        } else {
            cout << endl << "Error: Incorrect name or unable to open the file."
                 << endl;
        }
    } while (M.empty());

    return M;
}

int main() {
    string name = "test";
    Matrix data;
    data = input(name);

    /* Print the matrix*/
    for (size_t i(0); i < data.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j(0); j < data[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << data[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a stringstream to convert the type and make the type a template parameter of the function.

Comment: What format of CSV do you use ? More specifically what are the separators? spaces, commas, semicolumns, tabs?

Comment: The separators are comma between values in the same row, and newline (enter) between rows. There are no spaces or tabs in the input file, just numbers and commas. I will try using stringstream, but by the moment I continue being quite lost about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is to define the container that can store either type of value:

```
typedef struct {
  double fValue;
  std::string sValue;
  enum value_tag {type_string, type_float};
  value_tag type;
} CvsValue;

std::vector<std::vector<CvsValue> > Matrix;
```

You can then parse your CSV values and store in appropriate format. I would suggest to encapsulate the logic in CvsValue constructor.